# How to login / logout Facebook users to Facebook app?

Tags: python, facebook, oauth

I have a Google App Engine application that uses the Facebook login button to log Facebook Users in and out.  This works great.  Now I want to serve some content to a Facebook Application as an iFrame.  I have a separate branch of templates to serve content to the iFrame (the Facebook Application) and want to handle authentication without using the Facebook Login button (because it seems weird to have that button inside a Facebook page).

I'm using the Python Facebook SDK and the Facebook Javascript.

How do I track sessions without the Login button?

Comment: Not really an App Engine question - the fact that this is running on App Engine is incidental to your facebook auth issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the Facebook Javascript client library.  It will pop up a login dialog if they haven't logged in, or just give you their session info if they are already logged in.

```
FB.init({ appId: yourAppId });

FB.login(function (response) {
    if (response.session) {
        var authToken = response.session.access_token;
    } else {
        // do stuff if they are not logged in
    }
}, { perms: 'email,publish_stream' }); // list of extended permissions you require
```